# error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘void’)

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my code (I write the essence only) and I get this:

error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘void’)

```
class Mobil {
public:
void print() const; 
int  getNumber() const;
double getData() const;
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const Mobil&);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Mobil& mobil) {
    out << mobil.print() << endl;
    return out;
}
```

what is the problem?

Comment: @Rhathin that sounds like a perfect answer to me.

Comment: @Rhathin Don't answer in the comments section, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is this line: `out << mobil.print() << endl;`. Your `print()` method doesn't return anything (is type of `void`), so it can't be send to `ostream`.

To solve this problem, your `print()` method should return whatever you want to printout in one of types supported by `ostream` which you can find in [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

Comment: Or it can take `std::ostream&` and do whatever it needs to _on behalf of_ the `operator<<`, though this is arguably less idiomatic nowadays.