# no match for 'operator<<' in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

When I run this code, I get the following error
[Screenshot erore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGMCu.jpg)

50:7: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::__ndk1::ostream' {aka 'std::__ndk1::basic_ostream'} and 'void')
  cout << generateRandomNumber();
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
// class game
class mathGames 
{
public:
mathGames();
void generateRandomNumber();
void calculate();
void show();
void answer();
private:
int x;
int y;
int z;
char ans;
};
// constructor 
mathGames::mathGames()
{
x = 0;
y = 0;
}
// generate random numbers 
void  mathGames::generateRandomNumber()
{
srand (time(NULL));
x = rand()%9+1;
y = rand()%9+1;
}
// calculate numbers 
void mathGames::calculate()
{
z = x + y;
}
// show generate number 
void mathGames::show()
{
cout << " " << x << " + " 
<< y << " = " << z << endl;
}
// user answer 
void mathGames::answer()
{
cout << " true or false (t/f) ? ";
cin >> ans;
if (ans == 't') 
cout << 
generateRandomNumber();
}
// main
int main ()
{
mathGames number;
number.generateRandomNumber();
number.calculate();
number.show();
number.answer();
}
```

Comment: `cout << generateRandomNumber();` you cout void. `generateRandomNumber` returns nothing, you can't print nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic\_ostream<char>}’ and ‘void’)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224411/error-no-match-for-operator-operand-types-are-stdostream-aka-stdbasi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error it is showed becouse the function don't return anything (it is a void) and so it is impossible to print something.

Also if you want to store somewhere this random values you can pass to the function by address two argouments, in this way you can store the results here and don't lose them after you exit that scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning `void`. Therefore you cannot print anything.