# Why does it give me no match for operator the operand types are std:: basic stream and void in line 45

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Hey I am c++ newbie I am trying to display a vector, reverse it and rotate it in the same program I have passed the vector as Reference to avoid copying but it keeps giving me error I really don't know what's wrong.
Here below is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void FillArr(vector<int> &arr)
{
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        cin>>n;
    arr.push_back(n);
}
void PrintArr(vector<int> &arr3)
{
    for(int & v: arr3)
        cout<<v<<"\t";
}
vector<int> arr2;
void CopyReverse(vector<int> &arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        arr2.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    reverse (arr2.begin(), arr2.end());
}

void Rotate(vector<int> &arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        arr.push_back(arr[0]); 
        arr.erase(arr.begin()); 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
}
int main(){
    vector <int> arr;

    FillArr(arr);
    cout<<"Original array: "<<PrintArr(arr)<<endl;
    cout<<"Reversed array: "<<CopyReverse(arr)<<endl;
    cout<<"Original array after rotation: "<<Rotate(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because all your functions return nothing (i.e. `void`) but you're trying to print the result.

Comment: Removed the C tag. Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: @tkausl can you tell me what to do,plz??

Comment: A question for you to consider: What does `PrintArr(arr)` do, if you call it on its own?  What possible output do you expect `cout << "Original array: " << PrintArr(arr) << endl;` to have?

Comment: @paddy the original array before reversing or rotating it ..and if I called the function on its own it gives an infinite loop and the program crashes

Comment: You have one more problem in your `FillArr(vector<int> &arr)` function

Comment: @risingStark can you tell me what is it and how to fix It??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic\_ostream<char>}’ and ‘void’)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224411/error-no-match-for-operator-operand-types-are-stdostream-aka-stdbasi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you are making is that you are trying to print the output of the function call but the function do not return anything. You have several other problems in your code which I have also fixed. You can instead write your codes as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void FillArr(vector<int> &arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
}
void PrintArr(vector<int> &arr3)
{
    for(int & v: arr3)
        cout<<v<<"\t";
    cout<<endl;
}
vector<int> arr2;
void CopyReverse(vector<int> &arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        arr2.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    reverse (arr2.begin(), arr2.end());
}

void Rotate(vector<int> &arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        arr.push_back(arr[0]);
        arr.erase(arr.begin());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
}
int main(){
    int arrSize;
    cin>>arrSize;
    vector <int> arr(arrSize);

    FillArr(arr);
    cout<<"Original array: ";
    PrintArr(arr);
    cout<<"Reversed array: ";
    CopyReverse(arr);
    PrintArr(arr2);

    cout<<"Original array after rotation: ";
    Rotate(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Input:
The first line of input contains n, the number of array elements.
The next line contains n space-separated integers.

3
1 5 6

Output:
Original array: 1   5   6   
Reversed array: 6   5   1   
Original array after rotation: 6    1   5
```

Comment: just one more question: why do I have to define the vector size in the main is not the vector a fixed size array?

Comment: @Ayoub You can even work without defining the vector size in the main function. I did that because in your `FillArr()` function, you were running the loop from `i=0` till `i<arr.size()` and since there are no elements in the vector, the `arr.size() = 0`, so your array does not get filled. To avoid defining size in main function, you need to change the for loop of `FillArr()` function to `i<arrSize` and `arrSize` variable is either passed in the `FillArr()` function as a variable or you accept it as an input there itself in the `FillArr()` function.